# Angular http call fails with content-type json

Tags: angularjs, content-type

Here is my service:

```
home.factory("homeService", function ($http, $q) {
var service = 
{
    getAssets: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var response = $http({
            method: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: '',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': "application/json"
            },
            url: "http://localhost/myWeb/services/reports_ws.asmx/getData",
        });
        response.success(function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });
        response.error(function (data) {
            alert('Error');
        });
        // Return the promise to the controller
        return deferred.promise;
    },
}
return service;
```

I am getting 500 error from the server when I use application/json for the content. using plain/text works fine and data is returned, but in an xml format although the server sends data back in json format. I have tested it in Chrome, everything works fine. I also noticed that Chrome sends request using "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" for content-type. I tried it too, but still got data in xml. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Please check network tab in your browser's developer tools. If it shows XML then server sends XML ... It's as easy as it seems. Maybe you only THINK that the server sends JSON :-) Using `headers` option for $http will only change the request header, not the response header

Comment: The problem is on the server side. How did you change the content-type in chrome? I think that you send a form. So the data are send as inpputs not as a json object. The service method doesn't understand json format.

Answer (score 0):

keep trying with the following:

```
header: { "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
```

Please notice that this applies only for the header of the request, not the response. The response depends on your backend (server side).
Several ways are available to return JSON data in the response depending of the type of server you are using.

Comment: I am calling my web service in the browser and it does return json. Also, why would the server return 500 when I specify content type json if content-type for the client only?  My Web service method is not expecting any parameters.